# Quiero poner dos gráficas, una arriba de la otra en Rstudio. no logro visualizar bien

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

espero ser claro, es mi primer pregunta en el foro.

Tengo dos gráficos, el "A" es solo una variable y va graficado arriba (uso el mismo código en ambos gráficos pero filtro por "Especie" y "arte") y el "B" son varias variables graficadas con facet_wrap.
El gráfico debería quedar como esto:
[image: así queda bien distribuido]

pero me queda de esta manera:

[image: así queda mal distribuido]

he probado con grid.arrange y con patchwork, no logro acomodar bien las imágenes.
Debajo pego el código de la ultima salida, con patchwork.
Muchas gracias por sus tiempos.

Aqui el código:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(datos)
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)
library(esquisse)
library(patchwork)
library(gridExtra)

#1P.corruscans - todas las artes

frec_todas_artes <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>% 
  #filter(!(Arte %in% c("A – Todas juntas"))) %>%
  filter(Arte %in% "A – Todas juntas") %>%
  filter(Especie %in% "Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = `Rango`, y = `Porcentaje`) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color="white") + 
  labs(x="Largo total (mm)", y="Frecuencia relativa", title ="Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") +
  theme_bw () + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle = 90, vjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by=100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol=2)

frec_todas_artes

#2PCO - resto de las artes

frec_artes_facetas <- Frecuencia_de_tallas_por_arte_2023 %>% 
  filter(!(Arte %in% c("A – Todas juntas", "J – Maroma"))) %>%
  #filter(Arte %in% "A – Todas juntas") %>%
  filter(Especie %in% "Pseudoplatystoma corruscans") %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = `Rango`, y = `Porcentaje`) +
  geom_col(fill = "#0c4c8a", color="white") + 
  labs(x="Largo total (mm)", y="Frecuencia relativa") +
  theme_bw () + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "sans", face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size=8, angle = 90, vjust=0.5)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1600, by=100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 10)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(`Arte`), ncol=2)

frec_artes_facetas



#grid.arrange(frec_todas_artes, frec_artes_facetas, nrow = 2, widths = c(5,10))

#intento de reordenar con patchwork

frec_todas_artes / frec_artes_facetas +

plot_layout(heights = c(1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

En el sitio de Stackoverflow en ingles pude resolver este problema. dejo el enlace hacia allí.

[Enlace a la respuesta y solución en ingles.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848460/how-to-put-two-graphs-on-top-each-other-with-a-specific-layout/75850921#75850921)